# Associating Javascript classes/objects with HTML widgets/graphical objects, a la AS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, actionscript-3

TL;DR -- in the Flash world the IDE allowed you to associate an on-screen widget with a code class.  Is there a standard way to associate an on-screen graphical object (widget, DIV, etc) in the Javascript world? (Obviously there's no IDE here).

Please forgive me if this is too general or too poorly conceived, I'd appreciate not getting down-voted.  I'm coming from the (now defunct) world of OOP AS3 and would like to bring some of the techniques I learned there for structuring code to my Javascript coding.

One of the nifty things about AS3 was that it was quite easy to associate a Class with an on-screen graphical object, aka MovieClip -- one indicated in the IDE that a particular graphic object had a particular base class.  There was a one-to-one correspondence between the graphical object and the code, so that event listeners, data structures, etc were ready to go the moment it "came on screen".

Is this something that can only be done with a framework, e.g. Ember, etc, or is there another easy way to accomplish in JS?  I'm thinking conceptually of "adding" a DIV to screen (showing via CSS, for example) and having an associated class or object ready to handle events on it.

Comment: The question really is too broad for SO, but look at MVC/MVVM/whatever libraries/frameworks like React, Angular, Vue, Ember, and any of many others. They aren't quite what you describe, but they're *something* like it.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I've done some work with Ember.  I think that probably answers the question, but I'll see if anything else comes up.

Comment: There is an option to code JS objects with factory methods returning HTML elements with whatever you need appending them wherever you need. Having heavy AS3 background, I prefer to avoid writing any HTML directly